# AngularJS - Filter by array?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around something. I'm creating a function that I'm passing to a filter that filters out multiple fields. It looks like this:

```
$scope.searchFilter = function (obj) {
        var re = new RegExp($scope.query, 'i');
        return !$scope.query || re.test(obj.name) || re.test(obj.some_array);
    };
```

I can filter by a single parameter with no problem, but when it comes to arrays it completely ignores them. Do I have to write a for loop to iterate through the array or something? Hoping someone can help me figure this out.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: *"Do I have to write a for loop to iterate through the array or something?"* <- something like that, yes

Comment: @Phil that solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Phil solved it for me, just needed to write a for loop.